# Angular 7 auto-refresh bearer token

Tags: angular, authorization, jwt, interceptor, bearer-token

I have an AuthService, essentially with two methods:

- `getAuthToken` (returns Promise, so it can be lazily invoked / invoked multiple times with blocking wait on a single set)
- `refreshToken` (also returns a Promise, uses the refresh token available on the original JWT to request a new auth token)

I would like to automatically

- apply the bearer token to each http request (working)
- refresh the token on a refresh -- and I'm nearly there, except that the result of the request with the refreshed token doesn't make it back out to the original subscriber.

Here's the code:

```js
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpHeaders, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from "@angular/common/http";
import { from, Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";

@Injectable()
export class AuthHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private _authService: AuthService,
  ) {
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return from(this.addBearerToken(req, next));
  }

  private async addBearerToken(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Promise<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = await this._authService.getAuthToken();

    const headerSettings = req.headers.keys().reduce(
      (acc, cur) => {
        acc[cur] = req.headers.getAll(cur);
        return acc;
      }, {});

    if (token) {
      headerSettings["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${ token }`;
    } else {
      console.log("performing request without auth!");
    }
    // prevent 302 redirect to challenge on a 401
    headerSettings["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";
    const
      headers = new HttpHeaders(headerSettings),
      newRequest = req.clone({ headers });
    const result = next.handle(newRequest).toPromise();
    result.catch(async (err) => {
      if (err.status === 401) {
        const
          newToken = await this._authService.refreshToken();
        headerSettings["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${ newToken }`;
        const
          updatedHeaders = new HttpHeaders(headerSettings),
          updatedRequest = req.clone({ headers: updatedHeaders });
        console.log("requery with new token"); // <-- I see this when I have a 401, eg by altering the auth token to be bad, whilst leaving the refresh token alone
        return next.handle(updatedRequest).toPromise().then(data => {
          console.log("requeried data:", data); // <-- I also see this fire, with the valid data coming back from the second request
          return data; // <-- however the original caller doesn't get this data
        });
      }
    });
    return result;

  }
}
```

I have to assume this is probably due to my mixing of Observables and Promises (which I'm doing because AuthService is async, using Promises). Also, if there's no 401, the original call does come through correctly -- it's as if the promise chain is just dropped after the line

```js
next.handle(newRequest).toPromise();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Would it be possible to switch to Observables?

And, what happens if you return the promise at the end: return next.handle(updatedRequest).toPromise()

Comment: Returning from the original `.toPromise()` works -- and for requests without a 401 error, the above code works too.
Switching to Observables is probably possible -- but would impact other areas which expect a promise here; also the auth service stores the promise which resolved the last valid token so that subsequent calls can just get the last correct answer "as-is" -- which also handles if there are multiple callers trying to get a token and the first has triggered a refresh. Promises make that really simple -- I'm not sure how to translate that into Observables, tbh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're breaking the chain here:

```typescript
const result = next.handle(newRequest).toPromise();
result.catch(async (err) => {
  ...
});

return result;
```

`result.catch` returns a new Promise and your handler won't wait all the actions you called inside `catch`.

So you can write it as follows:

```typescript
const result = next.handle(newRequest).toPromise();
return result.catch(async (err) => {
  ...
});
```

Also what you probably want to do is **do not call refreshToken several times when one is in progress**

```typescript
cachedRequest: Promise<any>; // define prop in your class
...

if (!this.cachedRequest) {
  this.cachedRequest = this.authService.refreshToken();
}
const  newToken = await this.cachedRequest;
this.cachedRequest = null;
```

Here's a [**Simple Demo**](https://ng-run.com/edit/jq3HCneCcwhdy3WUZ84g) so you can test it. (*I handle 404 there but it doesn't matter*)

Comment: Well spotted -- it was the broken chain which caused the issue )':

Also, `authService` already deals with the multiple request scenario -- that's why it is async (ie, returns a promise) -- if an auth query is already in progress (or the last one already worked, callers just get back the in-progress or valid promise, so I don't have to care about caching requests or anything like that (:

Comment: (also, I have to admit that I feel rather silly at having been stumped at this -- not only have I consumed promises for literally years, I've written (4, iirc) promise implementations, twice for interest' sake, and twice (including the rewrite) for https://www.npmjs.com/package/synchronous-promise -- you'd _think_ I'd spot such a glaring mistake ): Still, thanks again, @yurzui!